# Getting a lot of "<classname> cannot be resolved to type" when installing SBT

Tags: eclipse, ibm-sbt

I have Eclipse Juno 4.2.1 installed on my Win7 x64 machine, and try to install "Social Business Toolkit SDK - 20131012". I unpack the content to C:\ ending up with C:\sbtsdk. Then I run the initWin.cmd to create the junction point (success), and unpack tomcat (jar doesn't exist, so I must unpack manually). Loading the workspace gives a lot of " cannot be resolved to type". Most certainly this is a kind of noob-error from my side where something isn't properly defined. On the other hand, in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsHxrccnO28, Bhavesh Shah, states that it should be extremely simple and fast to get going with the toolkit (fast forward to ~ 25:00 to see Shah's installation of Eclipse and toolkit). Anybody got any ideas on how to get past the front-door of SBT?

Update:
I saw another thing. For example, in the package com.ibm.sbt.core's com.ibm.sbt.services.client package I got an error referencing the Response-variable. It turned out that the Response.java file was actually located right in this package at location C:\sbtk\source\com.ibm.sbt.core\src\com\ibm\sbt\services\client, but for some reason wasn't referenced in the package. 
By adding Response.java to the package, the error went away (BTW, I didn't find "Add file to package" in Eclipse, so I had to copy the content to clipboard, delete the Response.java file, and then manually add a new file to the package with the correct name, and then paste the content. Probably a much better way to do this :-). 
But it is strange that the Response.java file wasn't referenced in the package, wasn't it?

Comment: did you add the references to the project?

Comment: @PaulBastide, I haven't set any other Project References that was was defined by default in the sbtk-Workspace (in other words, I just opened the workspace after creating the junction point with initWin.cmd).

Comment: And now I just tried to use the sbtsdk-1.0.0.20130620-0753 that Bhavesh S reference in his video. It opened up without any complaints! So, I guess its safe to say that the problems above lies in the new versions. So far I have registered;
A) The jquery180 project is specified in the settings, but the actual code is jquery182.
B)  com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.activitystreams.templates is referenced in the MANIFEST.MF or the core package, but doesn't exist anymore. 
C) The sample project referenced jars in wrong directory. Pointing them to correct location C:\sbtk worked